# Objective-C: NSJSONSerialization floating point number issue

Tags: nsjsonserialization

I'm using NSJSONSerialization to convert json string to NSDictionaray

the JSON string is

```
{"bid":88.667,"ask":88.704}
```

after NSJSONSerialization

```
{
    ask = "88.70399999999999";
    bid = "88.667";
}
```

Anybody know this issue?

Comment: did you find any answer ? ... i am facing this issue.

Comment: @mihirmehta no, I didn't.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `NSJSONSerialization` will serialize your values as doubles despite the fact that doubles are not precise enough to represent certain values exactly. See more detail here: [Does NSJSONSerialization deserialize numbers as NSDecimalNumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17986409/3565972)

If precision is not super important, you can simply round your values, but since you're dealing with what appears to be a financial application, it would be best to turn your values into integers by multiplying by 1000, serializing those, and then converting back:

```
{"bid":88667,"ask":88704}
```

An alternative is to use strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to get your exact value.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundUp];

NSString *strNumber = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:88.70399999999999]];
NSString *strNumber = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:88.667]];
```

Output will be 88.7 &
Output will be 88.67